# IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP behaviour inconsistency

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, udp, multicast

I have a use case in which I join the membership using IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP and after some time I have to IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP (just before drop seq id was 1) and then again I join the membership using IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP (for the same multicast group). I am noticing that I am getting the next packet (seqid = 2) which I think shouldn't be happening since as per my understanding IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP should stop receiving the udp packets and flush the socket it is using and once I joined back it should be the latest packet available and to this behaviour is not consistent sometimes I am getting the latest packet only.

Please note that I do not wish to close the socket. Continue using the existing one.

Please help. I am using Centos 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IP_MULTICAST_ALL to 0. It defaults to 1.

Explanation: With IP_MULTICAST_ALL 0 your OS will filter the incoming UDP packets to the groups you currently joined, which is what you expect in your description.

But this is not the default behavior on Linux.

The default (with IP_MULTICAST_ALL=1) is to receive *any* UDP packets which come into your socket. When you bound to 0.0.0.0 this will be all UDP packets the machine is receiving for that port, multicast and unicast, regardless whether you joined any multicast group or not. This means you will see all the artifacts of the difference between joining and leaving multicast group and the actual IGMP message sent by your machine, and you will also see all the artifacts and bugs of all the routers and switches you have in your local network. For example, when you leave a multicast group your OS may decide not to send the corresponding IGMP message at all, for example because some other socket is listening for this multicast address as well, or because the OS decides to leave with a delay. This is all perfectly allowed.

BTW, when you bind to the multicast address on Linux, this just has a filtering function and no binding function at all. You will then only receive UDP packets targeted at that particular multicast IP, regardless whether you also joined other multicast groups as well or not.

Regarding "flushing" a socket: The packet queues behind a socket are completely out of scope for your application. You cannot influence the queue state or behavior (except for reading from the queue or not) and you cannot expect any particular behavior.

In practice I would suggest:
- Bind to 0.0.0.0.
- Join and leave multicast groups appropriately.
- Inspect the target address of each UDP packet you receive and do any filtering yourself. Use IP_PKTINFO to get the destination address for each packet.
- Do not rely at all at routers and switches having any obvious and deterministic multicast routing behavior. Most of them have minute long timeouts for leaving multicast groups. This means that even when you left a multicast group (and even when you did not join) you may continue to receive multicast traffic for a couple of minutes. This masks bugs in your code and will cause a headache when trying to debug this.

This way you will not have to rely on any OS dependent behavior and you have full control of what you receive and what not.